# Win10 upgrade interrupted, Win7 Pro activation key now invalid?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10-upgrade

I decided to upgrade my Asus laptop running Windows 7 Professional to Windows 10. The upgrade app started properly, so I let it do all the pre-setup stuff, then started the upgrade. However, the power strip to which the laptop was connected somehow got shut off, so the computer ran out of power about 5% of the way through upgrading. When I turned back on the power strip, the computer reverted properly back to Windows 7.

After the computer finished restarting, I started over the process of installing Windows 10. However, after showing me the license agreement, the app gave me this message:

> Windows isn't activated on this PC. Use a product key to activate it before upgrading to Windows 10.
>   (If you don't have a product key, click on Support below.)

I pressed "Support", and was brought to [this page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/help-upgrade-windows-10), which has the following text under "Why do I need to activate Windows before I upgrade?":

> If you have a product key for your current version of Windows, but it doesn't work when you try to use it, go to the [**product activation**](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=270074) article for more help.

I clicked that link and followed the instructions in the Windows 7 section. But when I pressed "Activate Windows now", I received this message and the following options:

> The Windows 7 Professional product key you typed is invalid for activation
>   - Buy a new product key online
>   - Type a different product key
>   - Contact ASUSTeK Computer Inc. to help resolve this problem

I noticed that instead of "Activate Windows now", this text actually reads "3 days until automatic activation. Activate Windows now". I should also point out that I created a Restore Point before I originally started the Windows 10 upgrade process.

What should I try to do in this case? Should I <s>rollback to the Restore Point</s> (didn't fix anything), <s>wait the three days until it's automatically activated</s> (see below), or do something else entirely? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** The automatic activation timer has gone off, but the only thing that changed is that text, which now reads:

> 27 days to activate. Activate Windows now

Comment: You can try a restore point, but you may have to Use the Asus recovery media to reinstall W7, then try upgrade again.

Comment: @Moab Thanks for the tip. I tried the restore point, but it didn't seem to do much. The automatic activation timer is now down to 1 day, so I'll see what happens tomorrow and update this post as necessary.

Comment: Okay, so the automatic activation timer has gone off, but it wasn't re-activated. I guess I'll take the laptop to where I bought it, as they are prepared to install whichever version of Windows I prefer.